# How Do I Multiple Properties in Scripted Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to supply both choices and a poll trigger. I've tried a number of attempts, but no avail.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
properties(
        [parameters([choice(choices: 'dev\nprod', description: 'environment to deploy', name: 'DEPLOY_TO')])],
        [pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H/2 * * * *')])]
)
```

Comment: What doesn’t work, what’s the error message?

Comment: When a poll happens which choice will it take by default ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the proper formatting of the `properties` block

```
properties(
    [
        parameters([choice(choices: 'dev\nprod', description: 'environment to deploy', name: 'DEPLOY_TO')]),
        pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H/2 * * * *')])
    ]
)
```

I had the brackets and parens in the wrong places.

Comment: Appreciate posting the solution too!